# Removing 'is': which of these sentences is grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, verbs, present-simple

1. The program that performs Tagging is referred to as PoS Tagger and belongs to the group of Natural Language Processing (NLP) applications
2. The program that performs Tagging referred to as PoS Tagger and belongs to the group of Natural Language Processing (NLP) applications

In the second sentence, I removed the `is` after `Tagging`, and it still sounds correct to me?

Which of these sentences is grammatically correct?

Thank you.

Comment: If you remove _is_ you would also need to remove _and_, and enclose the phrase _referred to as PoS Tagger_ between commas or brackets.

Comment: If I don't remove 'is', is the sentence correct?

Answer (score 1):

The first is correct. There is verb in passive voice "is referred to" (present tense), The grammatical subject "The program that performs tagging" is the object of this phrasal verb.  It means "(Someone, We) refer to the program that that performs tagging as POS Tagger..."

(note, "tagging" is not a name, so not capitalised)

The second is wrong. There appears to be a past tense verb "referred to".  The thing that referred is a program (??) and grammatically there needs to be an object of "referred to".  The object is missing.  So the sentence is ungrammatical.

Comment: aha, got it. thank you so much.